# How to get IHTMLSelectElement Events in CDHtmlDialog?

Tags: html, c++, mfc, visual-c++-2010

I have html tag **select** in my html and want to get the select on change event in my CDHtmlDialog in MFC C++.

Just like i have to perform specific task with the selected option so i want select Element on Change event in C++ when value has changed.

Can anybody please help how i can do this??

Right Now i have added code like this:

```
 BEGIN_DHTML_EVENT_MAP(CHtmlWnd)


DHTML_EVENT_ONCHANGE(_T("on-font-name"), OnChangeFontName)
DHTML_EVENT(DISPID_HTMLSELECTELEMENTEVENTS_ONCHANGE,_T("on-font-name"),OnChangeFontName)
DHTML_EVENT_TAG(DISPID_HTMLSELECTELEMENTEVENTS_ONCHANGE,_T("select"),OnChangeFontName)

END_DHTML_EVENT_MAP()
```

But its not firing the event.

Please help in this regard.

Thanks